# Stream builder , builds the widget every time when the , when i come to that page , where the stream builder is used

Tags: flutter, stream, bloc

I am creating a crypto currency app using Flutter. Where all the coins list are present in one widget(page). I am using Streams and Bloc for statemanagement. price gets updated every 10sec.But when i come to the listing page every time the page gets refreshed again.

I need to retain the data. What should i use so that  page doesn't reload again when i come to that listing page again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to keep your state alive
Here is a link to you can checkout https://flutteragency.com/how-to-solve-automatickeepaliveclientmixin-is-not-working-with-bottomnavigationbar-in-flutter/